# angular- ngx-bootstrap throws error when running unit test with karma

Tags: angular

I am currently getting an issue with ngx-bootstrap running with Karma. 
The issue is  "*Chrome 57.0.2987 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Output' of undefined
at node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js:8087*"

I am using angular 4.0.0 and "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6". Here is my config

**1. package.json**

```
"dependencies":
  { 
        "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
        ........................
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6"
  }
```

**2. Systemjs.config.js**

```
  System.config({
  ......................
    map: {            
        // angular bundles
        ..............................
        'ngx-bootstrap': 'npm:ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',                     
    }

});
```

**3. karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
..................   
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'), // click "Debug" in browser to see it
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter') // crashing w/ strange socket error
    ],   
    files: [          
        ...................
       'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',         
    ]
```

............
    })
}

Please help me to figure out the issue. (Web app is running well with ngx-bootstrap)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In `karma.conf.js`, replace:

```
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js
```

with:

```
{
  pattern: 'node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/bundles/ngx-bootstrap.umd.js',
  included: false,
  watched: false
}
```

then it works.